# in responsive table second column value overlaps first column value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

when you reduce the browser window you will see a different lay out for the tables since i am using responsive tables....
the problem is in iphone screen layout some of the second column value overlaps with the corresponding row of the first column value....
how to avoid the overlap...

http://jsfiddle.net/bz2C4/embedded/result/

```
/* 
    Max width before this PARTICULAR table gets nasty
    This query will take effect for any screen smaller than 760px
    and also iPads specifically.
    */
    @media 
    only screen and (max-width: 760px),
    (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

        /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
        table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr { 
            display: block; 
        }

        /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
        thead tr { 
            position: absolute;
            top: -9999px;
            left: -9999px;
        }

        tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

        td { 
            /* Behave  like a "row" */
            border: none;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
            position: relative;
            padding-left: 50%; 
        }

        td:before { 
            /* Now like a table header */
            position: absolute;
            /* Top/left values mimic padding */
            top: 6px;
            left: 6px;
            width: 45%; 
            padding-right: 10px; 
            white-space: nowrap;
        }


        /*
        Label the data
        */
        td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "MFG P/N"; }
        td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "MFG Name"; }
        td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Part ID"; }
        td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Description"; }
        td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Cost"; }
        td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "Price"; }
        td:nth-of-type(7):before { content: "On Hand"; }
        td:nth-of-type(8):before { content: "On Order"; }
        td:nth-of-type(9):before { content: "Allocated"; }
        td:nth-of-type(10):before { content: "Shipped"; }
        td:nth-of-type(11):before { content: "Report"; }
        td:nth-of-type(12):before { content: "RMA"; }
        td:nth-of-type(10):before { content: "File"; }
        td:nth-of-type(10):before { content: "Add Part"; }
    }

    /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen
    and (min-device-width : 320px)
    and (max-device-width : 480px) {
        body { 
            padding: 0; 
            margin: 0; 
            width: 320px; }
        }

    /* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
        body { 
            width: 495px; 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the 'position:absolute;' from the generated content - see 
http://jsfiddle.net/ffYTa/

```
td:before{position:static;}
```